# Dose tracker with daily and weekly totals

Tags: python-3.x, functional-programming, comparative-review

This is an old script I made a while ago.

### What it does

It tracks your dose of whatever you want tracked (cigarettes, salt, etc), outputs the total for each day, and the full week.

### What I’m looking for

I’ve recently been looking at `map()` and list comprehensions so I converted this script into both versions.

I’d like to know if I’m doing it correctly and if I could do them better. I’d really appreciate some advice and help.

They all output the same thing:

#### output:

```
mon: 0 
tue: 0

Total -> changeme: 0changeme
```

1st version using `for loop`:

```py
days = [
   { "day_name": "mon",
        "taken_at": {
        '12:00': 0,
        '14:00': 0,
        '16:00': 0
        }
    },
    { "day_name": "tue",
        "taken_at": {
        '12:00': 0,
        '14:00': 0,
        '16:00': 0
        }
    }
]

dose_ray = []

unit = 'changeme'
substance = 'changeme'

for i in days:
    days = i["day_name"]
    dose = i["taken_at"].values()
    dose_per_day = sum(dose)
    print(f"{days}: {dose_per_day}{unit}")
    dose_ray.append(dose_per_day)

nl='\n'
print(f"{nl}Total -> {substance}: {sum(dose_ray)}
{unit}")
```

My first conversion was using `map()`, as I want to learn some functional techniques.

### map version:

```py
day = list(map(lambda x: x["day_name"], days))
nums = list(map(lambda x: sum(x["taken_at"].values()), days))

list(map(lambda x, y: print(f"{x}: {y}"), day, nums))
```

Then I converted to a list comprehension which is just a repetition of the map one:

### list comprehension version:

```py
day = [i["day_name"] for i in days]
nums = [sum(i["taken_at"].values()) for i in days]

[print(f"{i}: {x}") for i, x in zip(day, nums)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`map`, though it is functional, is not the only way to express a functional routine, and I dare say there are much more legible ways to do an equivalent operation.

First, your data structure itself would be better as an iterable of class instances, but for these purposes I've left it as a dictionary. The date and time data should be Python representations rather than strings.

It's possible, though not necessary, to do this loop-less:

```
from datetime import time
import calendar

days = [
   {
       'weekday': calendar.MONDAY,
        'taken_at': {
            time(12): 1,
            time(14): 3,
            time(16): 5,
        }
   },
   {
       'weekday': calendar.TUESDAY,
       'taken_at': {
           time(12): 2,
           time(14): 2,
           time(16): 1,
       }
   }
]

unit = 'mg'
substance = 'maple syrup'

print(
    '\n'.join(
        f'{calendar.day_name[day["weekday"]]}: '
        f'{sum(day["taken_at"].values())} {unit}'
        for day in days
    )
)

total_dose = sum(
    sum(day['taken_at'].values())
    for day in days
)

print(f'\nTotal -> {substance}: {total_dose} {unit}')
```

Printing one line at a time in a loop is also fine. But I would avoid `map`.

An alternative way to get the last dose total is

```
total_dose = sum(
    dose
    for day in days
    for dose in day['taken_at'].values()
)
```

which replaces the inner sum with an inner generator iteration.

Here is one example of an object-oriented approach that is simple, offers a little bit of validation, and is type-hinted:

```
from datetime import time
import calendar
from typing import Dict

UNIT = 'mg'
SUBSTANCE = 'maple syrup'


class DoseWeekday:
    def __init__(self, weekday: int, doses: Dict[time, float]):
        if not (0 <= weekday < len(calendar.day_name)):
            raise ValueError(f'{weekday} is not a valid weekday index')

        self.weekday, self.doses = weekday, doses

    @property
    def dose_total(self) -> float:
        return sum(self.doses.values())

    @property
    def weekday_name(self) -> str:
        return calendar.day_name[self.weekday]

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.weekday_name}: {self.dose_total} {UNIT}'


days = (
   DoseWeekday(
       calendar.MONDAY,
       {
           time(12): 1,
           time(14): 3,
           time(16): 5,
       },
   ),
   DoseWeekday(
       calendar.TUESDAY,
       {
           time(12): 2,
           time(14): 2,
           time(16): 1,
       },
   ),
)

print('\n'.join(str(day) for day in days))
total_dose = sum(day.dose_total for day in days)
print(f'\nTotal -> {SUBSTANCE}: {total_dose} {UNIT}')
```

Comment: Thank you I like it, I’ll use your python representations for the days and times, though I’d like to go loop less so I’m quite interested in what you’d do for that as this example was quite surprising @reinderien

Comment: Can you also show me what the data structure would look like as an iterable of a class, if you don’t mind? I’m also trying to learn classes but just can’t seem to grasp the point of them over using a file of functions

Comment: Edited. This is a way (though not the only way)

Comment: Thanks a lot I will learn from this :)